# What is TargetedPatchingOptOutAttribute?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TargetedPatchingOptOut: “Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109745/targetedpatchingoptout-performance-critical-to-inline-across-ngen-image-bounda)

When looking through .NET source code, I see the following relatively frequently:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
```

What is this for?